# Facebook and Google OAuth2 Sign-on not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, facebook-authentication

I'm following the Code! MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#) Tutorial. However when I grant the website the required permissions instead of displaying a similar page to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYtvK.png), I am redirected to [my login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmwTj.png). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No clue, but perhaps if you post some of your code and any exceptions you receive then we might be able to help.

Comment: Hey @DanWilson, I get no exceptions at all. As for the code, I followed the tutorial to the letter